# can't find import: "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, go, google-glass

I am using the [Google Glass Go](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-go) quickstart for Goggle App Engine.  And got stuck at this issues when starting the app:

> can't find import: "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"

I have a propper GOPATH and did get the outauth package with

> go get  code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth

I confirmed that the package is available at GOPATH. I ran various other Go App Engine apps without problems. Has anyone seen the same issue?

```
> go version
go version go1.1.1 (appengine-1.8.2) darwin/amd64

> go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="<EXISTING_PATH>/gopath"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="<EXISTING_PATH>/goroot"
GOTOOLDIR="<EXISTING_PATH>/darwin_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: What is the full text of the error message? What is the output of the `go env` and `go version` commands?

Comment: Updated the question with those.

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine for Go currently uses its own version of Go and also sets up a custom GOPATH. You need to put the sources somewhere in your `yourapp/` directory (preferable under the very same name of the package, e.g. `code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth/` so that a) the files get transmitted to the server during deployment and b) so that you local GAE environment can find them.

I think the Go GAE team is already working to remove those restrictions, but they haven't announced anything yet.